runtime-undefined behavior in the C++ standard
In section 3.50 of the latest draft of the C++ standard, there is this definition:

3.50[defns.undefined.runtime]runtime-undefined behavior
behavior that is undefined except when it occurs during constant  evaluation
[Note 1: During constant evaluation,
it is implementation-defined whether runtime-undefined behavior results in the expression being deemed non-constant (as specified in [expr.const]) and
runtime-undefined behavior has no other effect.
— end note]

Regarding the claim:
runtime-undefined behavior has no other effect.

What is the correct interpretation?
I am taking it to mean that the statement in total is essentially saying:

undefined behavior during runtime is not undefined during constant evaluation. you can either say it is non-constant and fail compilation AND no matter what, it mustn't have any other effect

I am not clear on what it means for it to have no other effect.
One possible interpretation is that if you choose to evaluate it anyhow and deem the expression constant, it mustn't affect the rest of the program beyond that expression.

As far as I can tell, in the current draft, there are only two things defined to cause runtime-undefined behavior: an assume which is not satisfied, and a noreturn function which returns.  For those, it's clear what it means to say "no other effect", in contrast to something like i = i++;.

Also notice that this is a Note and therefore not normative.  The normative language about it being implementation-defined whether it's a constant expression is expr.const p11.  The "no other effect" is normative by omission, in that no normative part of the standard specifies any effect.

Implementations are allowed to ignore attributes, which is fine when not ignoring them would mean undefined behavior since that doesn’t put any requirements on the implementation anyway.  However, during constant evaluation, implementations are required to diagnose (core-language) undefined behavior rather than misbehave due to something like an out-of-bounds access.
These two principles are in conflict for [[assume]] and [[noreturn]]; the answer is to release the implementation from its diagnostic obligation for them since “continuing execution” is an acceptable outcome for something that doesn’t produce any value or influence control flow.  The implementation can still choose to fail constant evaluation, though, since that’s a useful debugging feature.
